# How to find out if you are the Administrator

Tags: permissions

I am running a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and I am trying to find out what my administrative privileges are.

When I start up the pi I have started it in the standard mode after boot. I have not changed any settings at all or removed or installed any programs. When I try and open a folder called lost+found I get the following error

> Error operningf directory '/lost+found': Permission denied

I have used the `groups` command and I get the following message

```
pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games user input netev gpio i2c spi
```

**My Question:** Is there any way of viewing your user privileges and changing them to full administrative so I am able to access this folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX systems such as GNU/Linux use root filesystems where [each file has mandatory permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions) set on it.

The superuser (aka. `root`) on such a system can access anything.  Raspbian exploits [the sudo application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) to do something which would normally be considered moronic, since it short circuits a basic tenant of the permissions system, which is that a normal user used to e.g., browse the web, should not have permission to do anything.  But via `sudo` the `pi` user can. It's implicit in this that the default Raspbian configuration assumes:

- That anyone who uses the system as is has no real security concerns: Your pi is connected to your LAN and is a toy device.
- That the user is unfamiliar with file permissions, etc., and doing this makes it easy since you do not have to learn much about it, you just have to use `sudo`.

> Is there any way of viewing your user privileges and changing them to full administrative so I am able to access this folder.

You already have that as much as it is possible, you just have to use `sudo`.  Via this you can read and change permissions/ownership (see `man chmod` and `man chown`) on anything.

There are a couple of gotcha's, such as the fact that`sudo` does not work across [shell redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)).  However, you should be able to use `su` (switch user) to become `root` (i.e., `su root`).  If this does not work you may need to set a root password first via `sudo passwd root`.  Beware this is not the same as user `pi`'s password.

Answer (score 3):

By default, if you're not `root`, you're not "administrator". You can enter `whoami` at the command prompt to see who you're logged in as. If your user is a member of the `sudo` group (assuming you're running raspbian), you can execute commands as `root` using `sudo`. To see what groups your current user is a member of, enter `groups` at the command prompt.

This can all be customized, so all bets are off if you're using something than a stock raspbian configuration.

Comment: It says that I am running as pi, how do I change this to running as administrator so I can access my files? See Update for groups

Comment: @JakeSymons running everything as root and allowing root to login are major security issues, rather do as bobstro said and prepend the command with sudo.

Comment: And how would I go about doing this. I have tried to type in `sudo root` as that appear too be the instructions above but I get the message saying command not found.

Comment: @JakeSymons it is not sudo root it is sudo <command> so to do a directory listing you would do sudo ls or to change to a directory sudo cd lost+found. Since you seem very new to this I suggest you read the sudo man page using the following command man sudo. You might also want to read this https://www.learnenough.com/command-line-tutorial

Comment: I have typed that in and are still getting the same messages which says that sudo: cd: command not found.

Comment: It might help if you'd edit your question to explain what you're actually trying to accomplish rather than us try to guess line-by-line. You can get a root shell with `sudo -i`, but if you're learning, be *very* careful as it's easy to do permanent damage to your installation. If you are following instructions, and they assume you're root, they're either weak instructions, or meant for a higher skill level.

Comment: @JakeSymons try this sudo cat /etc/sudoers then try the same command without sudo. Sorry cd doesn't work because it is a shell built in.

Comment: @SteveRobillard both times says that cat: /ect/sudoers has no such file or directory.